Skybox doesn't get displayed on mobile Chrome in Unity WebGl
In my webgl build skybox is completely purple on mobile Chrome browser but works fine on PC and mobile firefox. Is there any fix for this?
Edit:
This is my skybox material and I didn't do anything special just assign it

Edit 2:
It appears same problem happens on Opera and Edge for mobile while safari and mozila work fine.

Can you show us what skybox material you're using and how you've configured it in your scene settings?

I edited the question with that info

I ended up using Mobile skybox shader and it seams to work, only problem here is that it needs split textures for skybox.
